# Setting UIWindow in AppDelegate without Storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on setting up a basic app without storyboards. I removed the storyboards line in `Info.plist` and I've set the following in my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

When I build and run, I get a simulator with a black screen rather than a full-screen of red.

My `UIViewController` class doesn't have anything in it other than the boilerplate that Xcode creates on creating a new project

```
UIWindow * window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[window setRootViewController:[[ViewController alloc] init]];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: can you try giving view controller view a color . I mean view background color in class and check.

Comment: I did that as well. Still black. Tried doing `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];` in the line right after `[super viewDidLoad]`

Comment: I'm not using storyboards in this project. That's why I'm doing this

Comment: sorry I forgot.

Comment: All good :) happens

Comment: @TusharSharma  check my solution hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use    self.window  not create new window

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.window setRootViewController:[[ViewController alloc]init]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: to use with xib       ` [self.window setRootViewController:[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil]]; `

Comment: got it mate . That's a correct point I didn't paid attention to.